# React Route In a Class Based Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to react and I was working o login redirects. What I am doing is to allow user to navigate in the whole app without logging in, if user then tries to submit a rating or a review, I want him to be redirected to login page, but since I am using class based components I cant find anything similar to **useHistory.push('/login')**, please help me in achieving this in class based components.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirect component: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect. Check if user is logged in and if not render Redirect component instead of your content.